# Abstracting duplicate lines of code in lambda functions in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I have 2 lambda functions which contains some duplicated lines of code as explained below in `organizeBooksFunc` and `organizeToysFunc`  functions. The rest of the lines of code are different.  In both case the values `path` , `value` and `organizedValue` are used in the rest of the code as well. Is there a way abstract the duplicate lines of code in both these functions?

```
  public interface OrganizerFunc {
    void organize(List<String> orgPath, Schema schema, Value value);
  }
```

```
public static void organizeBooks(){

    OrganizerFunc organizeBooksFunc = (orgPath, schema, value) -> {

        if(schema.isOrganizable()) {
            path = orgPath.get();
            value = PREFIX + value.get();
            organizedValue = callOrganizer(path, value);
            // Rest of the code below

       }

    }

}
```

```
public static void organizeToys(){

    OrganizerFunc organizeToysFunc = (orgPath, schema, value) -> {

        if(schema.isOrganizable()) {
            path = orgPath.get();
            value = PREFIX + value.get();
            organizedValue = callOrganizer(path, value);
            // Rest of the code below

       }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a class like the following:

```
@Data
public class SharedStuff {
    private String path:
    private String value;
    private String organizedValue;

    public SharedStuff(String orgPath, String schema, String value) {
        this.path = orgPath.get();
        this.value = PREFIX + value.get();
        this.organizedValue = callOrganizer(path, value);
    }
```

Then use like this:

```
public static void organizeBooks(){

OrganizerFunc organizeBooksFunc = (orgPath, schema, value) -> {

    if(schema.isOrganizable()) {
       SharedStuff sharedSuff = new SharedStuff(orgPath, schema, value);
       
        // Rest of the code below
        sharedStuff.getPath();

   }

}
```

}